# how to make flask pass a generator to task such as celery

Tags: flask, redis, rabbitmq, celery, generator

I have a bunch of code that I have working in flask correctly, but these requests can take over 30 minutes to finish.  I am using chained generators to use my existing code with yields to return to the browser.

Since these tasks take 30 minutes or more to complete, I want to offload these tasks but at am a loss.  I have not succesfully gotten celery/rabbitmq/redis or any other combination to work correctly and am looking for how I can accomplish this so my page returns right away and I can check if the task is complete in the background.

Here is example code that works for now but takes 4 seconds of processing for the page to return.

I am looking for advice on how to get around this problem,  can celery/redis or rabbitmq deal with generators like this?  should I be looking at a different solution?

Thanks!

```
import time
import flask
from itertools import chain

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=4

    def first_generator(self):
        b = self.a + 2
        yield str(self.a) + '\n'
        time.sleep(1)
        yield str(b) + '\n'

    def second_generator(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield '5\n'

    def third_generator(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield '6\n'

    def application(self):
        return chain(tc.first_generator(),
                     tc.second_generator(),
                     tc.third_generator())

tc = TestClass()

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def process():
    return flask.Response(tc.application(), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it's not clear what it would even mean to "pass a generator to Celery". The whole point of Celery is that is not directly linked to your app: it's a completely separate thing, maybe even running on a separate machine, to which you would pass some fixed data. You can of course pass the initial parameters and get Celery itself to call the functions that create the generators for processing, but you can't drip-feed data to Celery.

Secondly, this is not at all an appropriate use for Celery in any case. Celery is for *offline* processing. You can't get it to return stuff to a waiting request. The only thing you could do would be to get it to save the results somewhere accessible by Flask, and then get your template to fire an Ajax request to get those results when they are available.